# Adding a link to a span item

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to add a link on each item from this list, I tried using  but it breaks the animation and adds the first link to every item on the list, tried using data-url="link" inside the span, that doesn't work at all, here's the code, any help would be extremely appreciated.

index.html -

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>SKZ Romania</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">
      <span class="split-text" data-text="FORUM">FORUM</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <span class="split-text" data-text="LISTĂ BAN-URI">LISTĂ BAN-URI</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <span class="split-text" data-text="TOP RANK-URI">TOP RANK-URI</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <span class="split-text" data-text="DISCORD">DISCORD</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's library or framework do you using? Pure js ?
show us javascript code.

Comment: Please check your question and amend. First, in ' I tried using but it breaks the animation ' what did you try to use? I would have expected this to say something like 'an anchor tag'. Second, what animation? You have not shown us the CSS so we can't tell. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bxrqm8Qr
Here is the CSS, sorry

Comment: Please follow the instructions in the link I gave, don't use external repositories which may disappear. And please make a working snippet in your question, otherwise we are just guessing at answers.

Comment: It's ok, apparently what I'm trying to do is not possible, thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

try this one, i made a link for the first two items:

```
<ul class="list">
<li class="list-item">
<span class="split-text" data-text="FORUM"><a 
href="stylesheet" > froum </a></span>

</li>
<li class="list-item">
<span class="split-text" data-text="LIST? BAN- 
URI"> <a href="styles.css">  LIST? BAN-URI </a> 
</span>

</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add link to `span`. if you want to add link, You must use `<a>` tag !

for this you have to put the `span` inside the `a` tag like this:

```
<a href="http://yourUrl"> <span> your text </span> </a>
```

and for the animations, you have to change animation functions!

Comment: Doing this breaks the animation, so I guess I can't just simply add a link to this.

Comment: As I said, change your animation functions !
There is no way to add links to spans